# Testing using Arquillian in embedded Tomee: How to remove HSQL datasource?

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee

I am trying to test a session bean with persistence with Arquillian using embedded Tomee. But Tomee tries to connect to its default HSQLDB datasource.

AFAIK, I should instruct Tomee to use tomee.xml where the HSQLDB datasource is commented.

How can I do that using arquillian.xml? Or there is another way?

My deployment method:

```
    @Deployment
public static WebArchive createTestArchive() {
    MavenResolverSystem resolver = Maven.resolver();  
    File[] files = resolver.loadPomFromFile("pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();  

    for (File f : files) {
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
    }

    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClasses(MyBean.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsManifestResource("persistence.xml", "persistence.xml")
            .addAsLibraries(files);
}
```

My persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="oracle">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORADB" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="gk2" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="qwerty" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> -->
        <property name="hibernate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My arquillian.xml:

```
<container qualifier="tomee" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="httpPort">-1</property>
        <property name="stopPort">-1</property>
        <!--Optional Container Properties -->
        <property name="properties">
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem.

The data source should be configured in arquillian.xml:

```
        <property name="properties">
            oracle = new://Resource?type=DataSource
            oracle.JdbcUrl = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORADB
            oracle.JdbcDriver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
            oracle.UserName = username
            oracle.Password = password              
            ...
        </property>
```